# Nginx location match any path of Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-location

I want my nginx to serve a static `index.html` page from any request or path.
I have the following config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
    location / {
            root /var/www/project-name;
            passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

This works when the URL are "mydomain.com", or "abc.mydomain.com", but not "abc.mydomain.com/`users/sign_in`".

The error log of nginx is: `/var/www/project-name/users/sign_in` no such file or directory.

I've tried many regular expressions on the location, but no luck.

Update:
My index.html file is here `/var/www/project-name/index.html`

Comment: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` ?

Comment: Thanks @Deadoos. You point me to the solution. Your solution is to render the `index.html` file within `html` folder within `/opt/nginx`. So I just want to keep the default `index.html` as it is a welcome page of nginx, and name my static page to `static.html` instead. Plus, I need to remove `$uri/` since it renders `index.html` as default. So what works for me is `try_files $uri /static.html;`

Comment: However, it would be good if I can have and render my static page as it stays here `/var/www/project-name/`. But it seems this line of code always considers the last argument as a file inside `/opt/nginx/html`.

Comment: all `try_files` paths are `root` related. Inside the `location /` it would be `/var/www/project-name/static.html`. The `server` block does not contain `root` directive, so `nginx` gives an internal `/opt/nginx/html`

Answer (score 0):

`root` path in nginx point to `public` directory.

Try below code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
    location / {
            root /var/www/project-name/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Originally, I have my `index.html` as I describe above. I've tried add a public directory and have the `index.html` inside it, but still no luck with this error: `/var/www/project-name/public/users/sign_in` no such file or directory.

Comment: @PirunSeng try to move index.html file in `public` folder and try again.

Comment: I think you mean I should have something like this: `/var/www/project-name/public/index.html`. I got the same problem as my previous comment.

Comment: move index.html file in public folder and path is /var/www/project-name/public

Comment: I've tried as your suggestion but no luck. I have this file `/var/www/project-name/public/index.html` and this config `root /var/www/project-name/public;`

Answer (score 0):

I write down the answer just in case somebody else facing similar problem like mine. Thanks @Deadooshkha for pointing me out to the solution.
I will show two ways to render the static page. One is in `/opt/nginx/html` and another one is in `root` directory.

1. If you want to have your static page (`static.html`) inside `/opt/nginx/html`

   ```
   server { 
       listen 80;
       server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
       location / {
           try_files $uri /static.html;
           passenger_enabled on;
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you want to have your static page (`static.html`) inside root directory `/var/www/project-name`

   ```
   server { 
       listen 80;
       server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
       root /var/www/project-name;
       location / {
           try_files $uri /static.html;
           passenger_enabled on;
       }
   }
   ```